# JQuery - Hide table row based on table data;

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, microsoft-dynamics

I know very similar questions have been asked before, but i haven't been able to get anything to work, which may be due to platform (and the Jquery version its using);

I have a webpage displaying a table which currently looks like this;
[image]

The webpage is a Dynamics 365 ADX Portal page, its actual HTML is Bootstrap 3, and just this with some Liquid.  (Due to constraints of Dynamics, the Bootstrap & JQuery version can't be changed).
The table is actually an Dynamics entity view being embedded in the page.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-heading">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            {% for crumb in page.breadcrumbs %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ crumb.url }}">{{ crumb.title }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
            <li class="active">Company Invoices</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee;">
                <h2 class="tab-title">COMPANY INVOICES</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            {% block main %}
            {% include 'Page Copy' %}
            {% if page.adx_entitylist %}
            {% include 'entity_list' key: page.adx_entitylist.id %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}

    </div>
</div>
```

To then clean this webpage up & present it how the business wants, i have this Javascript on the page, which hides 3 columns & adds buttons.

What im trying to do is when td in 'status' column (which is hidden) has a value of "Cancelled System", then i want to hide this entire row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var portalUserId = window["Microsoft"].Dynamic365.Portal.User.contactId;
    $(".entitylist.entity-grid").on("loaded", function () {
    $('.entitylist').find("th:contains('Status')").hide();

     $(this).children(".view-grid").find("tr[data-id]").each(function (i, e){
        //debugger;
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $(this).find("td[data-attribute='statecode']").hide();
        $(this).find("td[data-attribute='statuscode']").hide();
        var status =  $(this).find("td[data-attribute='statuscode']")[0].innerText;
        var amount =  $(this).find("td[data-attribute='totalamount']")[0].innerText;
        var balance = $(this).find("td[data-attribute='ceda_balancedue']")[0].innerText;
        let issue_date = $(this).find("td[data-attribute='ceda_invoiceissuedate']")[0].innerText.split("/");
        let due_date = $(this).find("td[data-attribute='duedate']")[0].innerText.split("/");
        let today = new Date();
        const duedate = new Date(due_date[1] + "/" + due_date[0] + "/" + due_date[2]);
        const issuedate = new Date(issue_date[1] + "/" + issue_date[0] + "/" + issue_date[2]);
        if ((status == "Canceled") || (status == "Cancelled System")) {
            status = "CANCELLED";
            $(this).append("<td>CANCELLED</td>");
        }else if ((parseFloat(balance.split('$')[1]) < 0.00) || balance.contains("(")) {
            status = "CREDIT";
            $(this).append("<td>CREDIT</td>");
        } else if ((parseFloat(balance.split('$')[1]) > 0.00) && (duedate < today)) {
            status = "OVERDUE";
            $(this).append("<td style='color:red'>OVERDUE</td>")
        } else if ((parseFloat(balance.split('$')[1]) > 0.00) && (duedate => today)) {
            status = "OPEN";
            $(this).append("<td style='color:blue'>OPEN</td>");
        } else if (parseFloat(balance.split('$')[1]) == 0.00) {
            status = "PAID";
            $(this).append("<td>PAID</td>");
        }else if (parseFloat(balance.split('$')[1]) < 0.00 ) {
            status = "CREDIT";
            $(this).append("<td>CREDIT</td>");
        }
        
        //if((status == "BC Posted" || status == "BC Submitted" || status == "BC Submitted Failed" || status == "New") && parseFloat(amount.split('$')[1]) > 0){
        if ((status == "OPEN") || (status == "OVERDUE")) {
            $(this).append("<td><button class='btn btn-default pay' name = "+ id+","+balance + ">Pay</button></td>");
        }
     });
  });

  $('.table').each(function() {
      var $status = $(this).find("td").last().prev();
      var $row = $status.parent();

      if ($status.text() == 'Canceled'){
          $row.hide();
      } else {
          $row.show;
      }
  });
 /* additional code for button handling not displayed */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looping through the table and appending `<td>CANCELLED</td>` when you find a row that should be canceled:

```
if ((status == "Canceled") || (status == "Cancelled System")) {
  status = "CANCELLED";
  $(this).append("<td>CANCELLED</td>");
}
```

And after that you're looping through to find all the "cancelled" cells and then attempting to hide their parent row:

```
$('.table').each(function() {
    var $status = $(this).find("td").last().prev();
    var $row = $status.parent();

    if ($status.text() == 'Canceled'){
        $row.hide();
    } else {
        $row.show;
    }
});
```

I don't think this 2nd loop is necessary since you can just hide the "canceled" rows as you find them:

```
if ((status == "Canceled") || (status == "Cancelled System")) {
  status = "CANCELLED";
  $(this).append("<td>CANCELLED</td>");
  $(this).hide(); // HIDE PARENT ROW
}
```

If you still want to do the hiding in a separate loop, you'll have to find all the `<td>` elements with an innerText of "CANCELLED" (i.e. the ones you added previously) and hide their parents:

```
$("td:contains('CANCELLED')").each(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide(); // HIDE PARENT ROW
});
```

Comment: Something weird... i added just the `$(this).parent().hide();` in the existing if statement as suggested and all the rows were hidden.  So then i added a `$(this).parent().show();` to the else statements, and all the rows were displayed & nothing was hidden.

I then removed all those, thought id try the 2nd loop, and everything was displayed & nothing hidden.

Comment: @BlissSol Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71813138/edit) to include the `<table>` tag and a few sample rows, including one that is marked "canceled". Also, if you are hiding the rows in the same loop that you are adding canceled rows, you may need to change `$(this).parent().hide()` to `$(this).hide()`. Again, it's hard to say without seeing your HTML.

Comment: The HTML i listed is the HTML page (as far as we have access).  This is a MS Dynamics 365 ADX Portal website (it has limitations), and when the HTML page inserts the 'entity view' (via liquid coding in the HTML) it automatically handles <table><th><tr> & <td> tags.  Any JQuery\Javascript is a separate file on Dynamics, which gets injected in the page.  
With limitations - ADX Portal sites are bound & stuck on Bootstrap 3 (can't be upgraded) along with the JQuery version it uses. I'll post an image in the question of browser debug showing table etc.

Comment: changing code to $(this).hide(); fixed it - thanks!

Comment: @BlissSol Great! I've updated my answer to reflect the code change.